# How to pass a function to another function in order to create an action listener

Tags: python, pygame

I've been programming in Java for ~2 years, and have just started learning Python(about 1 week in) and PyGame, and have been wanting to create a simple button class, but I don't want the action of the button(what happens when it's pressed) to be hard coded in. What is the best way of doing this in Python/PyGame?

I've also thought of having a variable in the constructor, which is set to a function when it's called, like:
`def __init__(self, func)`

and called like

`act = action()
obj = Button(act)`,

I don't think this will work, but will get back to you all when I test it.

In Java, it would be called like:

```
button = new Button("Text");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       System.out.println("ACTION");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're close... it'd be more like `obj = Button(action)`. That is, don't call `action` when constructing the object, just pass the function object in and let the `Button` class call it when needed.

Comment: @kindall Ah yes, that is what I meant. Edited.

Comment: Why don't you want the action listener inside the class definition?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you are actually passing the return value of `action` as a parameter of the `Button` class?

Comment: @Rinzler I was not, hence why I asked the question

Comment: @Rinzler What do you mean by having the action listener inside the class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know you can pass a function object to another function is by passing its *identifier*:

```
# listener function
def listener(): 
    print('listening...')

class Button:
    def __init__(self, mouse_listener):
        mouse_listener() # you call the function inside __init__

button = Button(listener)
```

In Python, you can receive a function as parameter because functions are actually objects, but they are special objects, because they can be called or they are *callable objects*, in fact you could also call explicitly their `__call__` default function to invoke a function:

```
listener.__call__()
```

but usually you don't do that.

Comment: Yes, that is what I've been looking for(and what I tried out, but wasn't sure if it would work). Also, wouldn't you need to do `listener = listener()` before you created `button = Button(listener)`?

Comment: @GannonPrudhomme No, if you call the function and store the result in `listener`, you are actually passing the result or return value of the call to `listener()` to the constructor of the class `Button`. If you want just the result, I am not sure if it's an action listener...

Comment: When i do `def __init__(self, action)` and in that method call `action()` it returns `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, which I figure means I am basically trying to run a variable.

Comment: @GannonPrudhomme Exactly, you are passing a variable to the constructor instead of a function...

Comment: Then how do I run the function that is passed in the constructor/__init__ function? (`action` parameter) -- Scratch that. How do I set the parameter as a function without actually calling the function during the initialization?

Comment: @GannonPrudhomme You have to do exactly as I am describing in my answer: you have to pass the identifier of the listener/function and not the return value, and then call the function inside the `__init__` method

Comment: @GannonPrudhomme It's a feature of Python. What you are actually doing is passing a reference of the location in memory of that function to another function. You can do this because functions are objects in Python, and like any other object, you can pass them to functions as parameters

Comment: @GannonPrudhomme note that while you have your head tied up in functions returning functions, you should take a look at [function decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) which do exactly that. There's lots of pitfalls in this kind of thing, so be aware of how your returned function looks from the outside!